# boolean tags and rss feed

Tags: support, tags, rss

I subscribe to a couple tags' rss feeds, which is cool, and I would like to subscribe to a couple others but sometimes I am only interested in some of the questions that get a tag, and would like to limit the feed to questions that have two specific tags like vi-mode and bash or questions that have one tag but not another like bash and not cat.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to a feed of questions that have multiple tags by joining the tag names with `+`. For example, the feed of active [vi-mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vi-mode) [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) questions is https://unix.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/vi-mode+bash.

I don't think it's possible to have a feed that includes one tag and excludes another.